# Digital Potentiometer Not Working

Tags: beaglebone-black, digital-potentiometer

I am trying to control an [AD5206 digital potentiometer](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5204_5206.pdf) on a PocketBeagle (smaller Beaglebone Black essentially). I have an entry in my device tree for `spidev`, and I know the SPI pins are working because I can talk to a different chip on the bus (an MCP3208). I probed the CS line of the pot to make sure it was being selected during the write, which it was. However, I am measuring random resistances at the output of the pot (when measuring the resistance between DP0_B and AVCC).

Here is the relevant part of the schematic:

[image]

And the relevant code controlling it (this function gets called every two seconds in my main file):

```
int DigitalPotentiometer::setResistance(unsigned int channel, 
                                            unsigned int resistance) {

    // Create the 11-bit word
    unsigned int data[] = {channel, resistance};

    // Send the data over the SPI interface
    struct spi_ioc_transfer tr = {
        tx_buf        : (unsigned long)data,
        rx_buf        : (unsigned long)NULL,
        len           : 2,
        speed_hz      : 10000,
        delay_usecs   : 0,
        bits_per_word : 0
    };

    int retval = ioctl(this->_fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &tr);

    // Expected wiper settling time is 2us for the 10K variant, wait some extra
    usleep(5);

    return retval;
}
```

And the device tree file:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "ti,am335x-pocketbeagle";
    part-number = "mm-cape";
    version = "00A0";

    fragment@0 {
        target = <&ocp>;
        __overlay__ {
            P1_08_pinmux { status = "disabled"; }; /* SCLK - spi0_sclk - P1_08 */
            P1_10_pinmux { status = "disabled"; }; /* MISO - spi0_d0   - P1_10 */
            P1_12_pinmux { status = "disabled"; }; /* MOSI - spi0_d1   - P1_12 */
            P1_35_pinmux { status = "disabled"; }; /* CS0  - lcd_pclk  - P1_35 */
            P2_02_pinmux { status = "disabled"; }; /* CS1 - gpmc_a11   - P2_02 */
            P1_06_pinmux { status = "disabled"; }; /* CS2 - spi0_cs0   - P1_06 */
            P2_19_pinmux { status = "disabled"; }; /* CS3 - gpmc_ad11  - P2_19 */
            P2_07_pinmux { status = "disabled"; }; /* CS4 - gpmc_wpn   - P2_07 */
        };
    };

    fragment@1 {
        target = <&ocp>;
        __overlay__ {
            cape-universal { status = "disabled"; };
        };
    };

    fragment@2 {
        target = <&ocp>;
        __overlay__ {
            cape-universal@1 {
                compatible = "gpio-of-helper";
                status = "okay";
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <>;
            };
        };
    };

    fragment@3 {
        target = <&am33xx_pinmux>;
        __overlay__ {
            spi0_pins: spi0_pins {
                pinctrl-single,pins = <
                    0x150 0x30 /* SCLK - spi0_sclk (MODE0 | INPUT  | PULLUP) */
                    0x154 0x30 /* MISO - spi0_d0   (MODE0 | INPUT  | PULLUP) */
                    0x158 0x10 /* MOSI - spi0_d1   (MODE0 | OUTPUT | PULLUP) */
                    0x0e8 0x17 /* CS0 - lcd_pclk   (MODE7 | OUTPUT | PULLUP) */
                    0x06c 0x17 /* CS1 - gpmc_a11   (MODE7 | OUTPUT | PULLUP) */
                    0x15c 0x17 /* CS2 - spi0_cs0   (MODE7 | OUTPUT | PULLUP) */
                    0x02c 0x17 /* CS3 - gpmc_ad11  (MODE7 | OUTPUT | PULLUP) */
                    0x074 0x17 /* CS4 - gpmc_wpn   (MODE7 | OUTPUT | PULLUP) */
                >;
            };
        };
    };

    fragment@4 {
        target = <&spi0>;
        __overlay__ {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
            status = "okay";
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&spi0_pins>;
            cs-gpios = <&gpio2 24 0>, 
                        <&gpio1 27 0>, 
                        <&gpio0 5 0>, 
                        <&gpio0 27 0>, 
                        <&gpio0 31 0>;

            channel@0 {
                status = "disabled";
            };

            channel@1 {
                status = "disabled";
            };

            adc0: mcp320x@0 {
                compatible = "microchip,mcp3208";
                reg = <0>;
                spi-max-frequency = <1000000>;
            };

            adc1: mcp320x@1 {
                compatible = "microchip,mcp3208";
                reg = <1>;
                spi-max-frequency = <1000000>;
            };

            pot0: spidev@2 {
                compatible = "spidev";
                reg = <2>;
                spi-max-frequency = <1000000>;
            };

            pot1: spidev@3 {
                compatible = "spidev";
                reg = <3>;
                spi-max-frequency = <1000000>;
            };

            pot2: spidev@4 {
                compatible = "spidev";
                reg = <4>;
                spi-max-frequency = <1000000>;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is sending an 11 bit data word and that that byte and bit order are correct?  The other thing that looks strange is the 10000 Hz speed in the ioctl.

Comment: It is configured to send the 11 bits as two 8-bit transfers back-to-back, right-aligned (so padded with leading zeroes). The bit order is correct, but for sanity I have also tried swapping it with no success.

Comment: The timing diagram on page 5 of the linked datasheet has only 11 clocks. Are you sending 16?  I'm not sure that will work.

Comment: I am sending 16, but the internal function is specified to be a shift register with the last 11 bits clocked in being those that get latched. Other implementations on other platforms indicate that two 8-bit transfers should work.

Comment: So you are sending a byte with the three LSBs as the address followed by the data?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The array "data" in the C code contains these bytes.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me.  Is there any way you can look at the actual bits going into the pot?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I don't have a logic analyzer. I was only able to see CS going low because of a blip on an oscilloscope.

Comment: If you set up a repetitive loop in software you might be able to see the data portion on a scope.

Comment: try disconnecting AVcc from all the W pins

Comment: @jsotola they are connected through traces on the board. Though I could cut the traces I'd prefer to leave that as a last resort - what makes you think this could resolve it?